# Drupal PDOException error while enabling a module

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-theming, drupal-themes

I have installed the `ThemeTastic` theme and `themetastic_features` module, after enabling the themetastic_features I get the following error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072
>   Key column 'field_slider_block_bid' doesn't exist in table: CREATE
>   TABLE {field_data_field_slider_block} ( `entity_type` VARCHAR(128) NOT
>   NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The entity type this data is attached to',
>   `bundle` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The field instance
>   bundle to which this row belongs, used when deleting a field
>   instance', `deleted` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'A boolean
>   indicating whether this data item has been deleted', `entity_id` INT
>   unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The entity id this data is attached to',
>   `revision_id` INT unsigned NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The entity
>   revision id this data is attached to, or NULL if the entity type is
>   not versioned', `language` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT
>   'The language for this data item.', `delta` INT unsigned NOT NULL
>   COMMENT 'The sequence number for this data item, used for multi-value
>   fields', `field_slider_block_moddelta` VARCHAR(129) NOT NULL DEFAULT
>   '', PRIMARY KEY (`entity_type`, `entity_id`, `deleted`, `delta`,
>   `language`), INDEX `entity_type` (`entity_type`), INDEX `bundle`
>   (`bundle`), INDEX `deleted` (`deleted`), INDEX `entity_id`
>   (`entity_id`), INDEX `revision_id` (`revision_id`), INDEX `language`
>   (`language`), INDEX `field_slider_block_bid`
>   (`field_slider_block_bid`), INDEX `field_slider_block_moddelta`
>   (`field_slider_block_moddelta`) ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER
>   SET utf8 COMMENT 'Data storage for field 19 (field_slider_block)';
>   Array ( ) in db_create_table() (line 2720 of
>   /home/venice/domains/venice-stone.com/public_html/includes/database/database.inc).

Also I realized that after getting this error, when I enable any of my modules I get the same error too!

Also I took a look at database and could not find the table that this error is talking about!?

What should I do to solve the problem!?

Comment: As it is a paid for theme, we can't see the code.But the error says exactly what the problem is. The themes support forum is at: http://support.themeboutique.com/?envato_item_id=6230457

Comment: I'm not a drupal professional! Please tell me what does the error says!? what is the table name and what is the field name that does not exists!? I can create it myself.

Comment: It's messy since you need to add field metadata to make it all work, and you have no way to know that you won't get a different error when this one is fixed. Reporting a bug with the creators of the theme would probably be the smartest move

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is the problem of features module!

https://www.drupal.org/node/1604728

https://www.drupal.org/node/1679572

I tried unistalling and installing ThemeTastic: Features module and now everything seems to work well.